# autocomplete text input on select event

Tags: php, jquery

I have an autocomplete text input:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    var availableTags = <?php 
    $id_list = array("Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3");
    echo json_encode($id_list); ?>;

    $("#FacultyName").autocomplete(
    {
        source: availableTags,
        autoFocus:true
    });
</script>
<input type="text" id="FacultyName">
```

**Output:**
[image]

I want do some task when user select on the available tag.

Is there any function like `onClick` or `onChange` to do it?

Comment: Yes, onchange is what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autcomplete has a [select](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) event for this

Try like this

```
$("#FacultyName").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    autoFocus: true,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        alert("select");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has the .change() method. Here is the API documentation to help.

https://api.jquery.com/change/